# Python - FuzzyWuzzy - Loop Issue

Tags: python, loops, fuzzywuzzy

I am using fuzzy wuzzy for some word matching in Python. When I try and run a loop, I simply get no output. I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong?

I've recreated my problem with the code below:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz, process

choices = ['hello', 'world', 'today']
others = ['happy', 'today', 'colours']

for i in choices:
    print(i)
    process.extract(i, others)
```

Output:

```
hello
world
today

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Why is nothing happening for `process.extract()`?

I'd like this to try and match everything in 'choices' to everything in 'others'

Comment: Something is returned by process.extract, but you are not doing anything with it. What output do you expect?

Comment: Try: `print(process.extract(i, others))`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Think I was just being foolish